# Pattern Matching in List[(Double, Double)] with param filter

Tags: list, scala

I have this list:

```
val compensation: List[(Double, Double)] =  List.iterate((100.00, 100.00 ),5)( x => (x._1 *2, x._2 / 2) )
val sum = 400
```

that the output is:

```
(100.0,100.0)
(200.0,50.0)
(400.0,25.0)
(800.0,12.5)
(1600.0,6.25)
```

I have sum with someone of these elements (first argument) for example 400, and I want to sum first arguments until this val, in this case the total sum is 700.

I have that:

```
 def sum(xs: List[(Double, Double)]): Double = {
    xs match {
      case x :: tail => x._1 + sum(tail) // if there is an element, add it to the sum of the tail
          case Nil => 0 // if there are no elements, then the sum is 0
    }
  }
```

but I dont know how to put this val into the pattern matching and put one case with this filter, some like that:

`case x._1 > sum => 0`

best regards

Comment: As of now, it is pretty much impossible to understand what your requirement is. Can you provide input and expected output for your requirement ? Do you want the sum of all elements till you encounter an element greater than a given number (lets say 700. So your required sum will be 100 + 200 + 400. As the next number is 800 which is bigger than 700  ) ? Also, is your input list in sorted in increasing order ?

Comment: Or do you want the total sum to be less than 700 ?

Comment: I want to sum every element that will be <= sum, in this case sum = 400 that why the program need to sum 100 + 200 + 400 = 700. If sum will be 800 the program need to sum 100 + 200 + 400 + 800 = 1500

Answer (score 2):

```
def sumWithLimit(xs: List[(Double, Double)], limit: Double): Double = xs match {
  case Nil => 0
  case (x,_) :: tail if x <= limit => x + sumWithLimit(tail, limit)
  case    _  :: tail               => sumWithLimit(tail, limit) 
}
```

But a simpler (and better) solution:

```
def sumWithLimit(xs: List[(Double, Double)], limit: Double): Double =
  xs.collect{case (x,_) if x <= limit => x}.sum
```